# Middleware and populate field

Tags: javascript, strapi

I create my middleware in a plugin and I need to modify populated fields. For example, req URL is

`/v1/authors?populate%5Bpopulate%5D=%2A&populate%5BSomeRelationField%5D`

I need to add some field (for example `Tags`) in main response body and in all populated fields. Now I'm doing that like this

```
const Tags = await TagsService({
  strapi,
}).getTags({
  apiName: ctx.state.route.info.apiName,
  id: ctx.response.body.data.id
});
ctx.response.body.data.Tags = someField;
```

It modifies only the main response body but does not affect the populated field `SomeRelationField`.
How can I apply middleware to populated fields also?

I understand that I can't go through populated fields like `SomeRelationField` from the query but to get `Tags` I need to know `ctx.state.route.info.apiName` for each field (like `Authors` or `Posts` etc.).

What is the correct way to solve this?

My idea was to apply this middleware to populate strapi requests but I didn't find any info on how it's possible...

Comment: I couldn't understand your code example. Where does that `someField` come from? I also couldn't get the problem you face. Maybe you can give more details about your current model structure, your expectation from a request and the current response.